# Facebook Problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook

I am using facebook Graph API

Please suggest me what i do if

i have to post a feed on application wall and in that feed i have to upload an image with text.

This is done on when i post a feed through but i am unable do that with my objective c code for iphone.

this is attached code:

```
NSMutableDictionary *variables = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:2];


UIImage *picture = [UIImage imageNamed:@"zoom_image_search_screenshots.png"];


FbGraphFile *graph_file = [[FbGraphFile alloc] initWithImage:picture];


[variables setObject:graph_file forKey:@"file"];

[variables setObject:@"this is a test message: postPictureButtonPressed" forKey:@"message"];


//171256392921827 this is my application ID

FbGraphResponse *fb_graph_response = [fbGraph doGraphPost:@"171256392921827/photos" withPostVars:variables];
```

using this the photo upload in on my wall & create default album

Please suggest me whether it is possible through mobile if not please provide any document.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ankit the following code might help you to how to post a image on users wall in Facebook.
URL: http://www.raywenderlich.com/1488/how-to-use-facebooks-new-graph-api-from-your-iphone-app 

I hope it helped....

Comment: Thanks for your feedback
it will do what i have already done .......

i have to post on application wall & that image should upload in application directory not mine

Answer (score 0):

[FbGraph sample app](https://github.com/reallylongaddress/iPhone-Facebook-Graph-API) 
Download the fbgraph project for iphone from the above link, the code is properly commented you can understand quite easily. Hope this helps.